# How to past a list of lists to a function expecting *iterables

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I want the cartesian product of a bunch of lists.

```
from itertools import product

v1=['a','b','c']
v2=['1','2']
v3=['x','y','z']
list(product(v1,v2,v3))
```

This returns the desired result:

```
[('a', '1', 'x'),
 ('a', '1', 'y'),
 ('a', '1', 'z'),
 ('a', '2', 'x'),
 ('a', '2', 'y'),
 ('a', '2', 'z'),
 ('b', '1', 'x'),
 ('b', '1', 'y'),
 ('b', '1', 'z'),
 ('b', '2', 'x'),
 ('b', '2', 'y'),
 ('b', '2', 'z'),
 ('c', '1', 'x'),
 ('c', '1', 'y'),
 ('c', '1', 'z'),
 ('c', '2', 'x'),
 ('c', '2', 'y'),
 ('c', '2', 'z')]
```

However, I don't know the number of lists in advance. Suppose I have them stored as a list of lists `vs`, and I try to do this:

```
vs=[v1,v2,v3]
list(product(vs))
```

Of course, that doesn't give me what I want, because it treats `vs` as a single argument instead of multiple arguments.

```
[(['a', 'b', 'c'],), (['1', '2'],), (['x', 'y', 'z'],)]
```

Is there a way that I can pass a list of lists into `product` and have it operate on the sublists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a starred expression `list(product(*vs))`